# Using Q library in browser

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, q

I need to use `Q` library (http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) in the browser. I would like to use `RequireJS` to load this library, but I don't have any idea how to do this. I know how to load my own module, but I can't do it with `Q`. It has some function:

```
(function (definition) { 
  //some another code here***
  // RequireJS
} else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
  define(definition);
```

How can I load `Q` and then use it in another module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply load the Q library using a script statement in your HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.1.0/q.js"></script>
```

Then you can access it via the `Q` variable like so:

```
function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
function plus1(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

Q.fcall(function () {return 4;})
.then(plus1)
.then(square)
.then(function(z) {
    alert("square of (value+1) = " + z);
});
```

See this running at http://jsfiddle.net/Uesyd/1/

Comment: While this works, I think it's a bad idea since it means you're mixing modular (i.e. AMD/RequireJS) and "traditional" (i.e. global variables) code which can cause problems in the long run.

Answer (score 14):

The proper AMD way of doing this would be (borrowed example code from @Eamonn O'Brien-Strain):

```js
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    Q: 'lib/q'
  }
});

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

function plus1(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

require(["Q"], function (q) {
  q.fcall(function () {
    return 4;
  })
    .then(plus1)
    .then(square)
    .then(function (z) {
      alert("square of (value+1) = " + z);
    });
});
```

This way `Q` doesn't leak to the global scope and it's easy to find all modules depending on this library.

Comment: Probably, it is also required an entry in shim structure, because it is not AMD module:
`shim: {
      'Q': {
                exports: 'Q'
            }


    }`