# compiling node.js code to non-node-needed code

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am using `ASP.NET MVC` to build a web application, and I have fallen in love with the library `Q.js`, available here:

### [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Right now, I am using `version 1.0`, I load it up in the way that is most natural to me as an ASP.NET MVC developer. I have a place in my `BundleConfig` that just loads the script with my other scripts.

#### BundleConfig.cs

```
public static class BundleConfig {
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles){
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
         .Include("~/content/scripts/jquery.js")
         // lots of other includes
         .Include("~/content/scripts/q.js"));
   }
}
```

So then in my view `_Layout.cshtml`, it's the normal simple process...

#### _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</head>
```

Easy enough, right? Yes, it works fine. But I notice that `Q.js` has another **branch** labelled `v2`.

Now, from what I can immediately tell, they are not **that** much different, but I do not believe the creator would have made a version 2 if they were not doing it to improve the product. I'd like to try it out, but this is where my experience fails me.

version 2 seems fundamentally different than version 1. Here is a link to it for quicker reference; **[Qv2](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v2/q.js)**

The `q.js` file starts out with this at line `43`.

```
require("collections/shim");
var WeakMap = require("collections/weak-map");
var Iterator = require("collections/iterator");
var asap = require("asap");
```

I am accustomed to the `require` function being a part of `requirejs`, but I don't believe that is the purpose being served here. I in fact think this is intended to be consumed/run/used by `node.js`.

Now, since I am using `ASP.NET MVC`, I won't be using `node.js`. I've attempted to just put the expected folders and files in the right place so that they would be *path relative* to `q.js`, but that does not seem to satisfy it.

## The Actual Question

Is there a way I can *'compile'* `Q.js 2.0` into a `.js` file that will not require `node.js`, and can be loaded normally within my ASP.NET MVC project? Can I use `node.js` to actually create an output .js file that has everything I need?

Comment: Are you looking for [browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

Comment: http://browserify.org/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the very rapid feed back. I'll check this out. In the meantime, could I trouble one or both of you to actually post this as an official "answer", so that if you are right I can award you appropriate credit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I share code between Node.js and the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser)

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out too. I'm reading browserify right now and I am a bit confused. It looks to me like it is just another javascript library that runs in your code. So it's not something I use outside of my code to package it up?

Comment: `browserify` will enable you to use node/CommonJS style `require` calls and using `module.exports` to define modules yourself in a browser environment. This: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook is a pretty good reference, also this:http://www.myeyeson.net/gulp-js-and-browserify-with-asp-net/ may help you getting stuff set up in ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks again, I am sorry I seem so stupid with this. `node.js` confuses the hell out of me, to be honest.

Comment: I don't understand how browserify actually becomes aware of my project. Do I put a specific file in my ASP.NET MVC project? Or do I put this on my server, or my dev machine, or what? Is it just always there and looking at my javascript?

Comment: Apparently (since you seem to be using require.js) you can just shim `Q`'s export like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18827459/797194

Comment: Thank you all for all of your help. This actually gets me much further than anything I've tried previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[browserify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify) is a tool for Node that takes all of the `require()`d dependencies, resolves them, and packages them into a single JavaScript file servable to the browser.

Comment: FWIW, i thought of it on my own, before seeing the comments on the OP.

Comment: I am reading up on it right now, but I am still very confused about how to use it. Trying to see if I can find more examples. It seems to expect a lot of knowledge about node.js

Comment: Basic usage is actually pretty simple. Just create a Node.js file with `require()`s, run the `browserify` command from a CLI, and be done with it.

Comment: So I would download Q.js v2 from the github, and then open a command line, go to where that file is stored, and run `browserify` on it, and it will find the dependencies and output a working file?

Comment: Yep, provided all of Q's dependencies are available.

Comment: Well, I did it, and it did output a file, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error `Q is not defined` when I try to simply run `Q()`.

Comment: I've never used Q, so is it supposed to write to the global object?

Comment: I believe so, yes. That is at least present in a lot of its documentation

Comment: Hm. Sorry, I don't think I can help you further.

Comment: Understandable. This is further than I've gotten before! Thank you very much!